# hsqldb update failed throws 'assignment to generated column' Exception

Tags: sql-update, hsqldb

I have a update query. When i execute the below query it shows **assignment to generated column.**

Create Table Query :

```
CREATE TABLE  group1 (
  main_group varchar(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ('N/A'),
  group_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  group_id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(start with 1)
);
```

Update Query :

```
update group1 set main_group = 'Asset' where group_name = 'Current Assets'
```

Error :

```
Error code -5513, SQL state 42513: assignment to generated column
Line 1, column 1
```

I have checked with syntax is right.

Edit : Added Create table query for group1 table.

Help me out of this issue...

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please report the CREATE TABLE statement for the group1 table.

Comment: @fredt : I have updated the create table statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This table definition meas the value of main_group is ALWAYS generated as the string 'N/A'. It therefore cannot be updated. Obviously you do not want this. You should remove the `GENERATATED ALWAYS AS ('N/A')` clause.

If you want the default value of this column to be 'N/A' then use a DEFAULT clause. You should also define a primary key for your table.

```
CREATE TABLE  group1 (
  main_group varchar(20) DEFAULT 'N/A',
  group_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  group_id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(start with 1) PRIMARY KEY
);
```